# Can't get answer from server. ExtJs

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have a problem with submiting ExtJs form. I can't get a `success` function.

I have:

```
formp = new Ext.FormPanel({
 fileUpload: true,
 width: 350,
 autoHeight: true,
 bodyStyle: 'padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;',
 labelWidth: 70,
 defaults: {
  anchor: '95%',
  allowBlank: false,
  msgTarget: 'side'
 },
 items:[{
xtype: 'fileuploadfield',
id: 'filedata',
emptyText: 'Выберите файл для загрузки...',
    fieldLabel: 'Имя файла',
buttonText: 'Обзор'
 }],
 buttons: [{
text: 'Загрузить',
handler: function(){
formp.getForm().submit({
  url: url_servlet+'doUpload.jsp',
  success: function(formp, o) {
      alert(o.responseText);    
      }
                                             })
                                            }
 }]
})
```

in doUpload.jsp I have `out.println("1111");`
In fireBug I see that `doUpload.jsp` POST `1111` but not have a alert. What's wrong?

Comment: con you show us the full response?

Comment: out.println("1111"); this is all. Or u ask about something else?

Comment: I use this method when getting answer from another jsp and all works fine. I try send this `out.println("{success:true, file:'11111'}");` its work, but how to get a `11111` in alert?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.form.Basic-method-submit

```
//Respone object
out.println("{success:true, file:'11111'}");

//Submitting the form. The second parameter in the success callback is
//your response object. You can access it properties as shown below.
formp.getForm().submit({
  url: url_servlet+'doUpload.jsp',
  success: function(formp, o) {
      alert(o.result.file);    
  }
});
```